# gdb printing old and new value at a breakpoint hit

Tags: c++, gdb

I am debugging c++ code via gdb v7.10 .  I have a variable which is getting corrupted some where in my program . This variable is being used at 100s  of places but the potential places where it might get corrupted are 20 . 
I have put 20 breakpoints , but I want that when ever each of these 20 breakpoints are hit , I get the old and new value printed . I know with a single break point i can do a list of commands to be executed but I have 20 .

I cannot use a watch as then it hits at so many places that I cannot debug properly .

Comment: If you are suspecting variable corruption, probably Valgrind is the right tool to debug.

Answer (score 0):

`gbd` has a way of executing some commands using the `commands` instruction when a breakpoint is hit. Here is an example usage, which prints out the value of a variable and auto-continues:

```
 break 403
 commands
 silent
 printf "x is %d\n",x
 cont
 end
```

See [this](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'reverse debugging' feature of gdb to step back in time and see what the value was before it was changed - https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/reversible.html

The 'rr' tool takes reverse debugging a step further, you may want to investigate it as well - http://rr-project.org

Answer (score 0):

> I have put 20 breakpoints

That may not be the best way to debug this problem. Are you familiar with the `watch` [command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html#Set-Watchpoints)?

If your 20 places are the places where the variable is *modified*, then setting a watchpoint on the variable will stop exactly when you want to stop: when the variable changes its value.

As a bonus, stopping on a watch point prints the old and new value automatically.